# Persist UITableViewCell subclass property

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uicollectionviewcell

I have a `UITableViewCell` subclass that holds a `Bool`. This property should persist (while the cell is visible), however, I seem to have it set up so that when `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` is called, the property is reset. Example

```
class CellClass: UITableViewCell {

  var someBool: Bool = false

  func doSomethingWithBool() {
    if someBool {
      thing1()
      someBool = false
    } else {
      thing2()
      someBool = true
    }
  }
}



class CollectionView: UICollectionView {

  @IBAction func buttonPressed() {
    // Do some things

    // cellForItemAtIndexPath called again here
    self.collectionView?.reloadItemsAtIndexPaths(paths)
  }

  override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CellClass

    // Everything else

    if collectionViewProperty {
      // This doesn't work right because someBool is reset to false  
      cell.doSomething()
    }

    return cell
}
```

Do I need to set `someBool` in an `init` method? What is the correct way to design this?

Comment: Does the doSomething() function change someBool?

Comment: Yes, it changes someBool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would override prepareForReuse in your custom cell

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    someBool = false
}
```